# Why is the init argument being presented with an unexpected keyword?

Tags: python

I am trying to use the datefinder module with UK settings (i.e. day first in dates). I can see from the code that `__init__` contains an option for `first`, defaulting to `"month"` (see below). This, I wish to change.

```
class DateFinder(object):
    """
    Locates dates in a text
    """

    def __init__(self, base_date=None, first="month"):
...
```

Source: [datefinder GitHub repo](https://github.com/akoumjian/datefinder/blob/master/datefinder/__init__.py)

I have tried the below code, but it returns an error. Any thoughts where I am going wrong?

```
from datefinder import DateFinder

testString = 'here is some random text with a date of 2/11/1985 sat in the middle'
matches = DateFinder(first="day").find_dates(testString,index=True,source=True)

for match in matches:
  print(match)
```

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'first'
```

Comment: The version from PyPi (i.e. `pip install datefinder`) seems to be out of date from the GitHub src you linked. When I run `help(DateFinder.__init__)` I see `__init__(self, base_date=None)` note that there is indeed no `first` kwarg like in the linked src. Specifically that kwarg was added on Aug 2, 2020 https://github.com/akoumjian/datefinder/commit/9ee6ef9fba4e4ccfb6c07a5bcafb42567ca6c199 and the most recent Release was v0.7.1 on May 27, 2020 so there have been no recent releases that include that change

Comment: @CoryKramer Please post that as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

> The version from PyPi (i.e. `pip install datefinder`) seems to be out of date from the GitHub src you linked. When I run `help(DateFinder.__init__)` I see `__init__(self, base_date=None)` note that there is indeed no `first` kwarg like in the linked src. Specifically that kwarg was added on Aug 2, 2020 [github.com/akoumjian/datefinder/commit/...](https://github.com/akoumjian/datefinder/commit/9ee6ef9fba4e4ccfb6c07a5bcafb42567ca6c199) and the most recent Release was v0.7.1 on May 27, 2020 so there have been no recent releases that include that change

*-- [comment](/q/72062362/#comment127329786_72062362) by [Cory Kramer](/users/2296458/cory-kramer)*